# Cannot convert foreach to linq select

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert my foreach loop, as shown below into a Linq select statement

```
IEnumerable<string> tokensFromPlans = GetTokens();
foreach (var token in tokensFromPlans)
{
    DeleteFromQueue(token);
}
```

The above works fine.

I'm trying to convert it to Linq to learn about Linq.

```
tokensFromPlans.Select(token => DeleteFromQueue(token));
```

This fails with

> The type arguments for method … cannot be inferred from the usage

I'm very lost here. My understand for the Linq is we perform a select statement on the variable `tokensFromPlans`, which essentially iterations through the collection.

On each member in the collection, we call the function `DeleteFromQueue`

I can't understand what I'm getting wrong.

I have read [The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917249/the-type-arguments-for-method-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage) but I don't believe that is the issue as I'm not working with anything so complex.

Comment: `Select` should return a value. Obviously `DeleteFromQueue` returns nothing(void). You have chosen wrong method to practice LINQ. Instead find a logic where you need convert one collection into another, that would be good start for `Select`

Comment: Eugh… I think that is likely the issue. DeleteFromQueue is void!!! Can you move to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate for `Select` method should return a value.
Obviously DeleteFromQueue returns nothing(void). You have chosen wrong method to practice LINQ.

Instead find a logic where you need convert one collection into another, that would be good start for `Select`