# Issue with Migration from net core 2.1 to net core 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

After migration my entityframeworkcore from 2.0 to 7.0. I am getting the error in my customized code. Can you please help on this

```
 public static Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, int? id)
     where T : class
 {
     return SingleOrDefaultById(id, nonNullId => dbSet.FindAsync(nonNullId));
 }

 static async Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T, TId>(TId? id, Func<TId, Task<T>> searchFunc) where TId : struct
     where T : class
 {
     if (id == null)
         return null;

     var result = await searchFunc(id.Value);
     if (result == null)
         throw new DomainException($"{id.Value} is not a valid {typeof(T).Name}");
     return result;
 }
```

Here is the error detail:

The type arguments for method DbExtensions.SingleOrDefaultById(DbQuery, int?) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: It would help to know how you are calling this method from other parts of code. You can find information about the error through [Microsoft's error documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411) or through this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3917309/8839718)

Comment: Here is the detail where i am calling:

var test= await _dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefaultById(id);

Comment: You have already asked this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77785700/2501279), now deleted).

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, Yes i asked question and deleted because there was some issue with the question now i add the complete detail so that i can get some solution

Comment: Your code shows `SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, int? id)` but method on the screenshot is accepting `DbQuery`. How so? Do you have a full [mre] you can post somewhere like github?

Comment: There is one more method in the same class:

 public static Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbQuery<T> queryable, int? id)
     where T: class, ILookup
 {
     return SingleOrDefaultById(id, nonNullId => queryable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == nonNullId));
 }

I tried but not able to create some sample application to share for analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to:

```
public static Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, int? id)
where T : class
{
     return SingleOrDefaultById<T, int>(id, nonNullId => dbSet.FindAsync(nonNullId).AsTask());
}
```

And to prevent the warning, you need change the target type `Task<T>` to `Task<T?>`:

```
static async Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T, TId>(TId? id, Func<TId, Task<T?>> searchFunc) where TId : struct
```

Comment: I did this partially above problem solved but get issue in another method:

public static Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbQuery<T> queryable, int? id)
    where T: class, ILookup
{
    return SingleOrDefaultById<T, int>(id, nonNullId => queryable.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == nonNullId));
}


Error is:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<T?>' to 'System.Threading.Task.Task<T?>'

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type parameters for the call `SingleOrDefaultById(...)` -> `SingleOrDefaultById<T, int>(...)`:

```
public static Task<T> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, int? id)
    where T : class
{
    return SingleOrDefaultById<T, int>(id, 
       nonNullId => dbSet.FindAsync(nonNullId).AsTask());
}
```

Also note that second method should return nullable reference type (`T?`) since it can return `null`:

```
static async Task<T?> SingleOrDefaultById<T, TId>(TId? id, Func<TId, Task<T>> searchFunc) where TId : struct
        where T : class
{
   ...
}
```

P.S.

.NET 7 is soon out of support, next LTS is .NET 8 so I recommend upgrading to it.

Comment: Hi Guru,
I tried it but getting the following error now:

1) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<T?>' to 'System.Threading.Task.Task<T>'

2) Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly 
convertible to the delegate return type.

Comment: @nittinaggarwal sorry missed that `FindAsync` returns `ValueTask`. Call `AsTask` or use `async-await` in lambda. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve both the original error and the error you got from the other suggested answer by using the following (which also helps with your nullable values)

```
 public static Task<T?> SingleOrDefaultById<T>(this DbSet<T> dbSet, int? id) where T : class
 {
     // Can be simplified to 
     // SingleOrDefaultById(id, nonNullId => dbSet.FindAsync(nonNullId));
     return SingleOrDefaultById<T, int>(id,  nonNullId => dbSet.FindAsync(nonNullId));
 }

 private static async Task<T?> SingleOrDefaultById<T, TId>(TId? id, Func<TId, ValueTask<T?>> searchFunc) where TId : struct
     where T : class
 {
     if (id == null)
        return null;

     var result = await searchFunc(id.Value);

     if (result == null)
         throw new DomainException($"{id.Value} is not a valid {typeof(T).Name}");

     return result;
 }
```

EDIT: Screenshot to show there is no Syntax error caused by this.

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: I tried it but getting the following error now: 1) Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<T?>' to 'System.Threading.Task.Task<T>' 2) Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Comment: @nittinaggarwal Please check again rather than copy and pasting responses from your comments on other answers. This does not return either of these errors. I will edit the post to include a screenshot to prove this.